# Bernoulli naive bayes document model for multi-label classification

Tags: machine-learning

I want to ask about Bernoulli Naive Bayes document model. Can we use Bernoulli Naive Bayes document model for multi-label classification of documents?

Comment: did you mean to post this on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: cross posted on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276233/bernoulli-naive-bayes-document-model-for-multi-label-classification).